# Vuex big array processing via mutations and actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an array of about 1k...10k elements that must be processed.
The array is being stored in Vuex state.
The user should be able to process either a single element or to process all of them.
At first, when the array was quite small I used the mutation for single element processing and the action for all elements processing.
So the code was like this:

```js
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    array: [el1, el2, el3...]
  },
  mutations: {
    processEl: (state, el) => {
      ...
    }
  },
  actions: {
    processAll: context => {
      context.state.array.forEach(el => context.commit('processEl', el))
    }
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, as the array kept growing the action performance got poorer and poorer, so I found the solution:

```js
new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    array: [el1, el2, el3...]
  },
  mutations: {
    processEl: (state, el) => {
      ...
    },
    processAll: (state, el) => {
      function processEl (el) {
        ...
      }
      state.array.forEach(el => processEl(el))
    }
  }
})
```

It works much better but is there any more elegant solution that allows me not to repeat the `processEl` function content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `processEl` function in outer scope so it can be called from `processEl` and `processAll`.

```
function processEl (state, el) {
    ...
}

new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        array: [el1, el2, el3...]
    },
    mutations: {
        processEl,
        processAll (state) {
            state.array.forEach(el => processEl(state, el))
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, works well even thought it will be function `processEl (state, el) { ... }` so I'm not sure `state.array.forEach(processEl)` will work as intended.

Comment: Oh you are right, `processEl` has to access `state`. I have edited my answer. Thanks!